# Use jQuery element attribute to append to a matching element

Tags: jquery

I have some elements with an article class. These elements have a `paper-id` attribute. I want them to move into the corresponding div, which should have the class panel-`paper-id` where `paper-id` is the same as the `paper-id` attribute from the corresponding element.

I leave here an example using `jQuery(this)` (which obviously won't work), just to show what I need

```
jQuery('.article').appendTo(".panel-" + jQuery(this).attr('paper-id'));
```

Comment: Would you mind to post a sample of your `HTML` ?

Comment: Remember that `paper-id` is not a valid attribute while `data-paperid` is.

Comment: Use `data-` prefix for custom attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't** use invented attributes. For custom attributes always use `data-*` attribute.

HTML example:

```
<div class="article" data-paperid="2"> I'm paper 2 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {

    $('.article').each( function() {
         var myDataId = $(this).data('paperid');
         $(this).appendTo('.panel'+ myDataId);
    });

});
```

<sub>[Data attribute reference + guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6B9xk/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class='article' paper-id='1'>paper 1</div>
<div class='article' paper-id='2'>paper 2</div>
<div class='article' paper-id='3'>paper 3</div>
<div class='article' paper-id='3'>paper 3</div>
<div class='article' paper-id='4'>paper 4</div>

<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='1'></div>
<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='2'></div>
<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='3'></div>
<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='4'></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.article').each(function(i, el){
    $("div[panel-paper-id='"+ $(el).attr('paper-id') +"']").append($(this));
});
```

**Output**

```
<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='1'>
    <div class='article' paper-id='1'>paper 1</div>
</div>
<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='2'>
    <div class='article' paper-id='2'>paper 2</div>
</div>
<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='3'>
    <div class='article' paper-id='3'>paper 3</div>
    <div class='article' paper-id='3'>paper 3</div>
</div>
<div class='panel' panel-paper-id='4'>
    <div class='article' paper-id='4'>paper 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.article').each(function(k, v){
        $(".panel-" + $(v).data('paper-id')).append($(v));
    });
});
```

[**An Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CjwXf/1/)